# Move items from one sortable connected list to the other programmatically

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable connected lists `#left` and `#right`. I want to move all elements from `#left` to `#right` when clicking a button.

```
$('#left li').each(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.appendTo('#right');
});
```

Above function moves items but the `receive` function is not triggered.

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h66bmtf7/3/) of current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to trigger the `receive` event manually

```
$('#left li').each(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.appendTo('#right');

    // Trigger
    $('#right').sortable('option', 'receive')(null, { item: $this });
});
```

New [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h66bmtf7/4/)